# How to check at compile time that an expression is illegal?

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits, c++-concepts

I have a problem in my application where I'd like to assert that a function application would be rejected by the compiler. Is there a way to check this with SFINAE?

For example, assume that I'd like to validate that `std::transform` to a `const` range is illegal. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace ns
{

using std::transform;

template<typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2, typename UnaryFunction>
  struct valid_transform
{
  static Iterator1 first1, last1;
  static Iterator2 first2;
  static UnaryFunction f;

  typedef Iterator2                   yes_type;
  typedef struct {yes_type array[2];} no_type;

  static no_type transform(...);

  static bool const value = sizeof(transform(first1, last1, first2, f)) == sizeof(yes_type);
};

}

int main()
{
  typedef int *iter1;
  typedef const int *iter2;
  typedef std::negate<int> func;

  std::cout << "valid transform compiles: " << ns::valid_transform<iter1,iter1,func>::value << std::endl;

  std::cout << "invalid transform compiles: " << ns::valid_transform<iter1,iter2,func>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, my trait rejects both the legal and the illegal cases. The result:

```
$ g++ valid_transform.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
valid transform compiles: 0
invalid transform compiles: 0
```

Comment: `constexpr` might help, just a quick thought.

Comment: The other problem is that `std::cout << sizeof(std::transform(iter1(), iter1(), iter2(), func()));` compiles, while `std::cout << std::transform(iter1(), iter1(), iter2(), func());` does not.

Comment: @Lol4t0 That is because `sizeof()` does not evaluate it's arguments during compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is similar to [SFINAE + sizeof = detect if expression compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127693/sfinae-sizeof-detect-if-expression-compiles).

**Summary** of that answer: `sizeof` evaluates the type of the expression passed to it, including instantiating a function template, but it does not generate a function call. This is the reason behind Lol4t0's observations that `sizeof(std::transform(iter1(), iter1(), iter2(), func()))` compiles even if  `std::transform(iter1(), iter1(), iter2(), func())` does not.

Your concrete problem can be solved by evaluating the template from Lol4t0's answer for any output range that is to be supplied to `std::transform`. However, the general problem of verifying in a template that a function call will compile appears to be impossible to be solved with the `sizeof + SFINAE` trick. (it would require a compile-time expression that is derivable from a run-time function call).

You might want to try [ConceptGCC](http://www.generic-programming.org/software/ConceptGCC/) to see if this allows you to express the requisite compile-time checking in a more convenient way.

Comment: Your `OutputIterator` type can completely differ from `InputIterator` type, it depends on `Operator` return type

Comment: @Lol4t0 It only depends on whether OutIt can be converted to InIt.

Comment: You don't get the point: `OutputIterator` type can completely differ from `InputIterator` type, **but** `std:transform` still would work (and your validation will fail). [Example](http://ideone.com/12qfo).

Comment: Also note, that `std::is_const<Iterator>; std::is_const<Iterator::value_type>; std::is_const<Iterator::reference>;` do not work either :(

Comment: @rhalbersma: Thanks for your answer, but what I really want to validate is that the *implementation* of `std::transform` conforms to its spec, not whether a particular argument `is_const`. From your explanation, it sounds like I might not be able to.

Answer (score 3):

In my answer, I'dd like to focus on problem, how to determine, if given iterator constant:
`std::is_const` was mentioned, but it does not work in this case for me (gcc 4.7).

I assume, it is implemeted like

```
template <typename T>
struct is_const
{
    enum {value = false };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_const<const T>
{
    enum {value = true };

};
```

Now, one cannot check reference types with this struct, they would not match specialization, because `const T` would match `int& const`, that is *constant reference to int*, not `const int&`, that is *reference to constant int*, and first have no any sense.

Ok, but we are able to determine, if iterator is constant with the follwing struct:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct is_iterator_constant
{
    typedef char yes_type;
    typedef struct{ char _[2];}  no_type;
    template <typename T>
    static no_type test(T&);

    template <typename T>
    static yes_type test(...);

    enum {value = sizeof(test<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>(*Iterator())) == sizeof(yes_type) };

};
```

Comment: This is a nice trick. You might want to post this answer to this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193399/how-do-i-require-const-iterator-semantics-in-a-template-function-signature (Q is already 2 years old, but OP is still active) UPDATE: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423246/how-to-detect-if-a-type-is-an-iterator-or-const-iterator for a slightly different solution.

Comment: @rhalbersma, good links. fixed `std::iterator_traits` issue. :). I'll leave answer here for context.

Answer (score 1):

C++20 concepts have made it much easier to check for expression validity. Your solution with the *member detector idiom* works, but is much more difficult and much less efficient than a `concept` with  `requires` expression:

```cpp
template <typename Iter1, typename Iter2, typename UnaryFunction>
concept valid_transform = requires (Iter1 first1, Iter1 last1, Iter2 first2, UnaryFunction f) {
    transform(first1, last1, first2, f);
};
```

If you were really serious about this constraint, you would probably build a `concept` which includes all the constraints of the [`std::ranges::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/transform) function template.